# Angular momentum for planet is constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, celestial-mechanics

In this excersie we look at the system of the dwarf star Gliese 536. Gliese 536 is 10 Parsec away and has half the mass of the sun. (I guess, they mean our sun). There are hints, that there a so called Super-Earth is orbiting Gliese 536. We are interested in the movement of this planet around its star.

Assume we can aprox. the star and the planet as points of mass. Show that the angular moment $L=mr^2\dot \phi$ is a constant of movement. Meaning, it's constant over time.

Solution:

$\dot L = 2mr\dot r\dot\phi+mr^2\ddot\phi=mr(\underbrace{2\dot r\dot\phi + r\ddot \phi}_{=0})=0$

Question:
I do get that $\dot L = M = 0 \Rightarrow L=$const

but I don't get, why $2\dot r\dot\phi=0, r\ddot \phi=0$

I'd explain the first one, because $r=const$ thus $\dot r =0$. In the later, it seems, that I somehow should know, that $\ddot \phi = 0$ but I can't see why.

Am I assuming, that we have a stabilized systems of two planets? For me, this is just an general problem of 2 masses obriting each other, thus, $\phi$ can be anything for me so it isn't clear for me that it's second derivation vanishes.

So, why and under which assumptions is $d\ddot \phi=0$?

Comment: Please review your question. I cannot understand it. Define your terms, say who "they" are and what is the origin of your equations.

Comment: What is $\phi$? I can guess that it is the angle b/w the focus (Sun) and the plant but you should mention it.

Comment: I wrote the whole exercise down. It seems they are using polarcoordinates. So that's where $\phi$ comes from. Sorry, though it's obviouse.

Comment: Neither $\dot{r}$ nor $\ddot{\phi}$ are zero. You may want to review whatever material it is you were supposed to be familiar with on planetary motion.

Comment: Your question never said $r$ is constant. Can you post the unedited question?

Comment: Yeah, for $\dot r=0$ I just assumes $r=const$. (Because of the wording "it's 1' parsec away - although they didn't specify away from what.) I guess what is going on here is, that for a stable system of planets, we have $\dot L = 0$ and thus $2\dot r \dot \phi + r\ddot \phi=0$, hmm.

Comment: I posted exactly what I got.

Comment: I still have no clue about your coordinate system.

Comment: What force in the tangential direction could give you a $\ddot{\phi}$?

Comment: Yashas Samaga, you have the same information I got. For me it looks like they took a polar coordinate system with its center in the sun. But I think I was just able to clear my confusion. :)

Comment: @RobJeffries I'm not sure what you are asking, but for an elliptic orbit there most certainly is a tangential component of acceleration, due to the fact that the central force has a tangential component.

Comment: @Pirx and how do you arrange for $\dot{r}=0$ in an elliptical orbit. (As stated in the question). Or perhaps I misinterpreted.

Comment: @RobJeffries The way I read the question I thought $\dot{r}=0$ was an assumption that the poster had made, without deeper reflection, and simply in an attempt to get rid of that term. Notice that he presented this assumption in the "Solution" part of his question, and it was not part of the original problem. Of course, if I misunderstood then you are trivially correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term $2\dot r\dot\phi+r\ddot\phi$ is the component of the acceleration along the direction of $\hat\phi$ (in polar coordinates). Since there is no force along this direction (the gravitational force is central so it lies on the radial direction) this term vanishes.

Comment: okay, thanks. That makes sense. I also just noticed that they exersice assumed (without telling), that: $F_{external}=0, M_{external}=0$ and $M=\dot L=0$ For me $M=0$ wasn't clear. Thanks to everyone, and sorry for the rather poor question.

Comment: This is not correct; for an elliptic orbit there most certainly is a tangential component of acceleration, due to the fact that the central force has a tangential component.

Comment: @Pirx You are right. By "tangential" I meant the component along the $\hat \phi$ direction of the polar plane coordinates. I was a bit sloppy with terminology but the answer is correct though. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct, but the clarification is important. If we just say "tangential direction", a natural assumption would be for this to refer to the direction tangential to the object's path.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a logical derivation, this is what I remember from my mechanics class. Start with the polar form of some position vector $\vec x$. Then you calculate the acceleration to show that a force which only has a tangential component (which is the case for gravity) implies constant angular momentum.
$$\vec x(t)=r\ \hat e_r$$
$\hat e_r$ is a unit vector pointing to $\vec x$ which makes an angle $\phi$ with the x axis. This unit vectors varies in time and its derivative can be found using the chain rule. We define $\hat e_\phi$ as a unit vector at 90 degrees of $\hat e_r$

$$\hat e_r=\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos \phi\\\sin \phi\end{array}\right)\quad \frac{d\hat e_r}{dt}=\left(\begin{array}{c}-\sin \phi\\\cos \phi\end{array}\right)\dot \phi=\dot\phi\ \hat e_\phi$$

Similarly $\frac{d}{dt}\hat e_\phi=-\dot\phi\ \hat e_r$

Using the product rule twice we find

$$\begin{align}\frac{d\vec x}{dt}&=\dot r\hat e_r+r\dot\phi\hat e_\phi\\
\vec a=\frac{d^2\vec x}{dt^2}&=(\ddot r-r\dot\phi^2)\hat e_r+(2\dot r\dot\phi+r\ddot\phi)\hat e_\phi\end{align}$$
giving us the general acceleration in polar form. In the case of the attraction between two bodies, the force (so also the acceleration) only has a radial component: the part in front of $\hat e_\phi$ is zero. So we have proven that $2\dot r\dot\phi+r\ddot\phi=0$. Note that $\dot r$ doesn't need to be zero to have constant angular momentum.